# How to input a variable as the pattern in re.sub while using ^

Tags: python

I am trying to use the re.sub to replace every character in a string, (word), with ' _ ' except for my variable character , (answer), and I am having trouble getting re.sub to properly read (answer), which is in string form, while using ^. I am able to get it to read (answer) properly when I am not using ^. I've tried using .format() but this also doesn't seem to work for me. When I run it in it's current state it replacces all the characters in the string with ' _ ' instead of just the non-answer characters. (Note: I am extremely new to python so I apologize for any bad code)

```
known_word = (re.sub('[^{}]'.format(answer), ' _ ', word))
```

Current Output, assuming word = 'coffee' and answer = 'e':

```
known_word = ' _  _  _  _  _  _ '
```

Expected Output, assuming word = 'coffee' and answer = 'e'

```
known_word = ' _  _  _  _ ee'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup as described in the question produces this output, which is what you say you expect

```py
import re
word = 'coffee'
answer = 'e'
known_word = (re.sub('[^{}]'.format(answer), ' _ ', word))
known_word

# Output:
# ' _  _  _  _ ee'
```

So, we need to look for the error elsewhere. Doublecheck your answer and word inputs?

To answer the broader question, you should use [`re.escape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) when inserting arbitrary text into a pattern. But for the given string `"e"` it doesn't make a difference.

```
re.sub('[^{}]'.format(re.escape(answer)), ' _ ', word)
```

Comment: This is only a small piece of my code, is it possible that having both word and answer as variables may be messing things up on my end?

Comment: Probably not faithfully translating to the minimal reproducible example in the question. I.e the code is different. I would suspect that rather than some technicality.

Comment: it ended up being some formatting errors that were messing with the values of BOTH (word) and (answer), thank you for being so patient.